# Change label in tkinter inside a class? StringVar()?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to construct a game where you can play five-in-row and when someone wins I want the label to change from like "Game is going on" to "Player 1 won" and this is where I am stuck.

The way I have constructed it all is like this. I have one class for the graphics (a Frame) and I have one class for all the Buttons that you can click on to set it to "X" or "O". And then I have one last class that checks if the grid has five of some value in a row, and that one runs after each successful click.

The label is of course set in the Frame class and first I had it like this just to make sure that I could see something

```
def __init__(self, master = None, rows = 10, cols = 10):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    Some other selfs....
    self.inforad = Label(master, text = "Game is going on")
```

and this prints out nicely, just like I want it. Now I have been trying for hours to make this change when someone wins and I just can't make it work! The last thing I tried is to use the StringVar() and I did it like this

```
    self.info = StringVar()
    self.info.set("Game is going on")
    self.inforad = Label(master, text = self.info)
```

and for starter this doesn't work at all, it prints out PY_VAR0. My plan was to define a method to call this during the game, like this

```
 def disp(self, string):

    self.info.set(string)
    return self.info
```

And this doesn't work at all. Can someone help me with this? I am really new to programming, did my first code for like 3 weeks ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(If `self.inforad` is placed within the Frame subclass instance, `self`, its `master` should be `self`, not the master of self.)

As for your specific question, change `Label(master, text = self.info)` to `Label(self, textvariable = self.info)`.

Comment: "(If self.inforad is placed within the Frame subclass instance, self, its master should be self, not the master of self.)"   
  
Can you explain this?

Comment: Now its working, I had to change text to text variable! :) The master thingy seems to be right, if I change it to self it will create a whole new tab and mess everything up, maybe its something in the rest of the code that you aren't aware of :) Anyway. THANK YOU! :)